# How to scan a QR code in a non web node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, qr-code, scanning

So I'm kinda new to JS and I want to make an app that is always watching for QR codes. When it finds one it reads and does something, then goes back to watching for other QR codes. This app won't be needing a display and will be running on a raspberry pi with a camera so there's no need to have a frontend or a server.

So far I only found how to do it on web apps and in client side. That is my last resort.

Edit:
I found a way to do it by using [jsQR](https://github.com/cozmo/jsQR) and [node-webcam](https://github.com/chuckfairy/node-webcam#readme).

Comment: If you found a way you could elaborate by answering your own question and helping other users. Be careful to avoid link-only answers, since they are subject to link rot.